# How to stop someone from sending emails from my domain using hotmail

Tags: hotmail

Someone on our organization used his corporate email account as secondary email account on hotmail, so he could send email from hotmail that looked like it was sent from our servers.

He no longer works here and his email account was disabled but the account is still linked to his hotmail account and he is still sending email messages that seems to be from our organization.

I've already roperted him to abuse@hotmail.com but i don't know if it's the right place to do it, is there any automatic way to unlink his account?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot. Hotmail will have to deal with it themselves. However because this is an organization and his secondary email clearly identifies the organization address, the folks at Hotmail will have no doubts about your report and the problem should be dealt with swiftly.

Comment: Isn't it realizeable with a .htaccess file?

Comment: @Chris. No. This is not going anywhere near the OP's mailservers. Hotmail is sending mail with a spoofed `From` address (perfectly respectable behaviour). There is no way any configuration change on the OP's servers (except the SPF mentioned by CarlF) could affect this.

Answer (score 3):

Your organization could set up [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) (Sender Policy Framework).  SPF is a system where the owner of a domain can specify which servers are entitled to send email using that domain in the From address.  For instance, I used the [Beveridge tester](http://tools.bevhost.com/cgi-bin/dnslookup) to query superuser.com, and it turns out that they have specified the Google mailhosts only to send mail as someone@superuser.com.  If your Hotmail-using ex-employee tried to send mail from him@superuser.com, SPF-compliant servers would either reject the mail or assign it a higher spam score.

Note that details of setting up SPF are ServerFault stuff, not SuperUser.  In fact, your question is arguably a ServerFault question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If he is costing you money, you can sue him for damages. If not, talk to an attorney to get an injunction and also get attorney’s fees, even tough just a letter by him or her may just do the trick.